# Customize reference system

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

My problem is the following :

I want a reference to another section to be like that :

"See **section 3.2**"

I tried `\textbf{section~ref{section}}` but there are two problems :

1. Only the number of the section is an hyperlink and I want the "section" also to be an hyperlink.
2. This is not automatic ...

How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have a look at the `cleveref` and `varioref` packages

Comment: There are two ready-made solutions: (a) Load the `hyperref` package and use `\autoref`; (b) load the `cleveref` package and use `\cref`.

Comment: `\autoref` is pretty good : it is what I want but there is a red box at the border of the reference. Is there a mean of getting rid of that ?

Comment: I finally found : `\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{                    
    colorlinks=true,                
    breaklinks=true,                
    urlcolor= black,                 
    linkcolor= black,                
    citecolor= black                
    }`

Comment: \autoref*{...}` should do also, without setting explicit hyperref options